# Updating JSON file with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I would like to update a JSON file using my AngularJS app.

Here is my service:

```
myGallery.factory('galleryData', function ($resource,$q) {

return $resource('./data/gallery.json', {}, {
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
    'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
    });
});
```

My controller is:

```
myGallery.controller('GalleryController',
    function GalleryController($scope, galleryData)
    {
        $scope.galleries = galleryData.query();       
        $scope.addGallery = function (newGallery) {
            $scope.galleries.push({
                name: newGallery.name                    
            });

            newGallery.name = "";
        };

        $scope.saveGallery = function () {
            $scope.saveGallery.$update();
            // ???
        };
    });
```

but in the save method, I don't know what I have to do.
Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is json,can you explain it to a newbie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695883/what-is-json-can-you-explain-it-to-a-newbie)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a file just like that. You will need to write some server-side handling for that situation and update the file manually with request data.

Implementation depends on what server technology do you use.