# Update a query value using javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I know that this might be answered already by someone, but all the answers I could find, are intended for people who already know what they are doing and they paste thousands of lines of code, so I want something more on a begginer's side.

I have a value that I want to update ever 15 seconds to show the most updated information from a mysql db. I managed to show the latest result every once you reload the webpage.

The code is the following (everything is on the same file index.php):

PHP part:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$LastUpdate = mysql_query('SELECT dateTime FROM LastUpdate where id=1');
if (!$LastUpdate) {
die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
```

HTML part:

```
<small id="result">Last Update: <?php echo mysql_result($LastUpdate, 0); ?></small>
```

Jscript part:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
var date='Last update: '+'<?php echo mysql_result($LastUpdate, 0); ?>';
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = date;
}, 1000);
```

The script part is supposed to refresh the "result" div every 1000 milliseconds. The problem is that once the script is performed one time the value gotten from the query doesn't change, having to reload the page in order for it to refresh.

Comment: Use an ajax request to do that

Comment: Where is your db ?

Comment: your java script code is working fine  check the below plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Ogx40uWPY2oALq4FigQf?p=preview . give your code a try by increasing the interval from 1000 miliseconds

Comment: @Akshay as I said "I want something more on a begginer's side." I would be glad to use it, but I don't even know how.

Comment: @Rishi my db is at the localhost, the connection and queries work perfectly.

Comment: @Deep I know the code is working, I tried replacing the query with a date time aswell and it worked, but when I replace it with the sql query, that value is static unless i refresh the page which is what I want to avoid. Also increasing the time to 15000 milliseconds didn't help.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions since they have been deprecated since a few versions back, and finally removed in PHP 7.

Comment: On another note... you could try ask google for something like "ajax tutorial". That would probably give you 20000+ pages where you can learn on how to do it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's an exaample I found at the php official webpage. What should I use instead? Would that solve my problem?

Comment: You should use `pdo` instead.. it would not solve your problem, my other comment would (about learning ajax).

Comment: Add this at the end of your php code  `echo mysql_result($LastUpdate, 0);` , now do an ajax request inside the `setInterval` like this `$.ajax({url: "yourURL.php",method:"POST",data:yourData, success: function(result){$("#result").html(result);}});`, you might want to add a `isset($_POST["yourDataName"])` inside the php code

Comment: @Akshay - You forgot to mention that your example depends on jQuery to work, It's not pure JS.

Comment: Yup forgot about that  @MagnusEriksson thanks :) can't edit it now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all. Client asks Server for Webpage -> The Server build your Page -> The Browser get the response and render your HTML page. So far so good. Your `<?php echo mysql_result($LastUpdate, 0); ?>` always has the same value. You have to make an AJAX call and please don't use mysql functions anymore. There are deprecated (https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-connect.php). Use PDO instead and always escape your statements to prevent sql injections or use an ORM. Here is a quick and dirty solution:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function ajaxCall() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (data) {
                $(this).addClass("done");
                var date = 'Last update: ' + data.firstData.dateTime + ' - count: '+ data.secondData.count;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = date;
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            ajaxCall();
            setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <small id="result"></small>
</body>

</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('testdatabase', $link);

$LastUpdate = mysql_query('SELECT dateTime FROM LastUpdate where id=1') or die(mysql_error());
$firstData = mysql_fetch_assoc($LastUpdate);

$count = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(Name) AS count FROM users, LastUpdate WHERE lastConnection = dateTime') or die(mysql_error());
$secondData = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);


$returnValues = array(
    'firstData' => $firstData, 
    'secondData' => $secondData
);

echo json_encode($returnValues);
```

response example (JSON)

```
{
    "firstData": {
        "dateTime": "2016-06-16 00:00:00"
    },
    "secondData": {
        "count": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably wrap the `ajaxCall()` and `setItnerval()` in an onload, like `$(function(){  ...you code... });` to be safe.

Comment: The function should still be outside the onload.. it's the `ajaxCall()` and `setInterval()` that should be inside..

Comment: Updated. I can also put the `ajaxCall()` outside the scope ... and so on. This is only an example.

Comment: Yes. But when helping people, it's best to be as accurate as possible. :)

Comment: @Phil The code u gave here works fine,but I don't know how can i add another query to be sent "SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM users,LastUpdate WHERE lastConnection=dateTime

Comment: @Phil how/where do I use that json code? I'm completely lost when it comes to web programming.

Comment: JSON is a way to structure data, Its like XML. Most of all APIs use it. Its simple and every language can understand it. They have functions, classes or extensions to do that. 
In your case, I gave `$.ajax` the `dataType: "json"` parameter. JQuery knows what to do. Excepts a JSON-String, forms it into an object and you can iterate over it or call specific values. On the PHP side, I only called the `json_encode()` function to build a valid JSON-String out of the given array.(http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695982/6429774) Sorry, if my english is a little bit strange.

Comment: @Phil okay but now I'm lost, I pasted the index.php where my index, and the  ajax.php at the ajax file and it doesn't seem to display anything now. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: if you have a blank page, turn php errors on and open the "network" tab in your browser dev tools. Maybe this is an error with your database.